# Convert frozen graph from .pb to .onnx

Tags: python, tensorflow, onnx

I have a TensorFlow graph frozen as a `.pb`, and I would like to convert it into the `.onnx` format. I am currently trying using mmconvert (from Microsoft's [MMdnn](https://github.com/Microsoft/MMdnn)) and apparently I am doing something wrong (see code below). Is there any other recommended approach for converting a `.pb` into an `.onnx`? Thanks.

Here's the command I am using:

```
mmconvert -sf tensorflow -iw /frozen_models/model.pb --inNodeName input --inputShape 512 -df onnx -om tf_mobilenet --inNodeName input
```

Which gives the error

```
ValueError: Need to provide the output node of Tensorflow model.
```

Answer (score 4):

The Onnx format requires an output node to be specified in the model. A quick glance suggests mmconvert expects that to be specified with --dstNode.

If you're converting a TensorFlow graph to an Onnx Graph, you could also use [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx).

You would convert the model with the command:

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --input /frozen_models/model.pb --inputs input --outputs outputNodeName --outputoutput tf_mobilenet.onnx
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @csteegz! I I tried using the command you suggested, and this is the output I got: `ValueError: Input 0 of node Gs/Assign was passed float from G_synthesis_1/lod:0 incompatible with expected float_ref.` The entire output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/albusdemens/85c5d7965ed8b0f718527ac3c5fd5203). Do you have any suggestion on how to fix the problem?

Comment: It looks like an issue with restoring the weights, but that's a very vague understanding. 
I'd suggest opening an issue in their Github repo or trying with a [saved model](https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/guide/saved_model) instead of a frozen one, it might do a better job of restoring the weights before converting them.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I fixed that issue and got a new one regarding the `:num` issue. Will post the issue on GitHub.

Comment: I think that tf2onnx works only with TensorFlow 1.* models. How to do with TF 2.*?